# AEM CQ5 How to modified a parent page and at meantime the child page get modiedly automatically

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem

How to modified  a parent page and at meantime the child page get modified automatically? without use the MSN livecopy , because we don't have the license.
anyone can help ? thank you very much.

For example, I want to change a text value in parent page, and meanwhile I want the same text in child page could be changed automatically.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issue. What exactly are you modifying in the parent page and what exactly in the child page needs to be modified accordingly? And what is the use-case for this ?

Comment: For example, I want to change a text value in parent page, and meanwhile I want the same text in child page could be changed automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you right, but I see two possibilities:

1. iparsys: This is an inheriting parsys. So any component placed within this will be inherited to child pages. You can break the inheritance on any level
2. Reference: There is a Reference component in the foundation where you can reference any component from another page by its path.

In both cases, if the original component gets changed, the inheriting or referencing page will get the update as well.

Comment: I am new to aem and english is not my mother tongue. thank you very much.